# Different user page for multiple user level

Tags: php, mysql, admin

Diferent user page for multiple user level.
Where should i put this code to redirect to different pages for each user level.
And maybe I have some errors. How should it be?

```
        $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];
        if ($_SESSION['role'] == "normalUser")

   {
              //do stuff here for users
              header('Location: memberpage.php');
   }
         else if ($_SESSION['role'] == "profesor" ) 
                                   {
              //do extra stuff here for only profesor 
             header('Location: profesori.php');
  } else {
             header('Location: admin.php');
```

This is user.php

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            return $stmt->fetch();

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username,$password){

        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];   
            $_SESSION['Fname'] = $row['Fname'];
            $_SESSION['Lname'] = $row['Lname'];
            $_SESSION['indeks'] = $row['indeks'];
            $_SESSION['module'] = $row['module'];
            $_SESSION['semester'] = $row['semester'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['titula'] = $row['titula'];
            $_SESSION['kabinet'] = $row['kabinet'];


            return true;
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }
    }

}


?>
```

This is login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('includes/config.php');


if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php');exit; } 


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];



    if($row = $user->login($username,$password)){ 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        header('Location: memberpage.php');
        exit;

    } else {
        $error[] = 'Погрешно корисничко име или лозинка, или вашиот акаунт не е активиран.';
    }

}


$title = 'Најави се';


require('layout/header.php'); 
?>


<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
            <form role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
                <h2>Ве молиме најавете се!</h2>
                <p><a href='./'>Врати се на почетна!</a></p>
                <hr>

                <?php
                //check for any errors
                if(isset($error)){
                    foreach($error as $error){
                        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$error.'</p>';
                    }
                }

                if(isset($_GET['action'])){

                    //check the action
                    switch ($_GET['action']) {
                        case 'active':
                            echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Вашиот акаунт е активиран, можете да се најавите.</h2>";
                            break;
                        case 'reset':
                            echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Проверете го вашето сандаче за линкот за промена на лозинка.</h2>";
                            break;
                        case 'resetAccount':
                            echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Лозинката е променета, можете да се најавите.</h2>";
                            break;
                    }

                }


                ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Корисничко име" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" tabindex="1">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Лозинка" tabindex="3">
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                         <a href='reset.php'>Ја заборавивте лозинката?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Најави се" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>


<?php 

require('layout/footer.php'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would recomend to you change attitude about roles admin / professor and everything else should be student (it's more secure, because in your case, if you forget to add role, user will be admin by default).

My second recomendation is you should validate if the user in the session is really user object and not only loggedin value. This validation shoud also be in the User class.

And login.php file code looks wrong. You have to use the User class and you should make login, session values management and checking roles exclusively through this object.

And finally your question - redirecting to specific page should be within login form processing.